# Optimal MySQL index for search query within date ranges

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table of the form

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fieldA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldB` int(11) NOT NULL,
....
)
```

The table will have around 500,000,000 rows, with the remaining fields being floats.

The queries I will be using will be of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE fieldA= AND fieldB= AND timestamp>'' and timestamp<='' 
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

At the moment I have two indices: a primary key on id, and a unique key on timestamp,fieldA,fieldB (hashed). At the moment, a select query like the above takes around 6 minutes on a reasonably powerful desktop PC.

What would the optimal index to apply? Does the ordering of the 3 fields in the key matter, and should I be using a binary tree instead of hashed? Is there a conflict between my primary key and the second index? Or do I have the best performance I can expect for such a large db without more serious hardware?

Thanks!

Comment: You removed your indexes

Answer (score 4):

For that particular query adding an index to `fieldA` and `fieldB` probably would be optimal. Order of the columns in the index do matter.

**Index Order**

In order for Mysql to even consider using a particular index on the query the first column must be in the query, so for example:

```
alter table mytable add index a_b_index(a, b);

select * from mytable where a = 1 and b = 2;
```

The above query should use the index `a_b_index`. Now take this next example:

```
alter table mytable add index a_b_index(a, b);

select * from mytable where b = 2;
```

This will not use the index because the index starts with `a`, but `a` is never used in the query so mysql will not use it.

**Comparison**

Mysql will only use an index if you use equality comparison. So `<` and `>` won't use an index for that column, same with `between`

**LIKE**

Mysql does use indexes on the `LIKE` statement, but only when the `%` is at the end of the statement like this:

```
select * from mytable where cola like 'hello%';
```

Whereas these will not use a index:

```
select * from mytable where cola like '%hello';
select * from mytable where cola like '%hello%';
```

Comment: MySQL uses (b-tree) indexes for ranges.

Comment: I've made a new table with this key, but inserting the data is now taking a rapidly increasing amount of time - the first 150k rows took 20 seconds to insert, the second double that, and so on to the point where the heat death of the universe will occur before all my rows are inserted. Is there any way to work around this, or is it an inherent limitation with calculating b-tree indexes?

Answer (score 3):

Hashed indexes are not used for ranges. They are used for equality comparisons only. Therefore, a hashed index cannot be used for the range portion of your query.

Since you have a range in your query, you should use a standard b-tree index. Ensure that fielda and fieldb are the first columns in the index, then timestamp. MySQL cannot utilize the index for searches beyond the first range.

Consider a multi-column index on `(fielda, fieldb, timestamp)`.

The index should also be able to satisfy the `ORDER BY`.

To improve the query further, select only those three columns or consider a larger "covering" index.